# Use induction and Pascal's Identity to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{r}C(n+k,k) = C(n+r+1,r)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I know Pascal's Identity is ${n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}{n-1 \choose k}$, but I am not sure how to set up and use the proof to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{r}C(n+k,k) = C(n+r+1,r)$.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: By $C\sum_{k=0}^{r}(n+k,k)$, do you mean the sum of all combinations, i.e., $\sum_{k=0}^{r}C(n+k,k)$? The notation is slightly confusing.

Comment: Oh Yes! Let me change that. Thank you for asking that.

Comment: No worries, I changed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

First verify $r=0$, then prove an induction on $r$ using Pascal's identity.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: Do you have trouble with the induction step, or with the case $r=0$?

Comment: I am having trouble with both.

Comment: OK what does the identity (that you need to prove) look like when $r=0$?